# How do I serve index.html with .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I have an angular app at `someip.com/mysite/`

In my `.htaccess`, I have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /mysite/index.html [NC,L]
```

Within my angular code, it redirects to `someip.com/mysite/reservations/new` and Apache tries to look for that instead of just serving `index.html`

What am I doing wrong?

There's one additional condition.. `someip.com/mysite/admin` should serve the `admin.html` page instead of `index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First comment other rules & try this rule in root directory

```
DirectoryIndex admin.html index.html
```

here if there is some directory exist it must contain index.html file and if there is no index.html file or admin.html is present in admin folder it will make admin.html as index of that particular directory.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need rewriteRule for this, just use DirectoryIndex directive

```
DirectoryIndex /index.html
```

Comment: Seems easy. I forgot to mention the admin aspect. See the updated question.

Comment: Also, that didn't work. Instead I did `DirectoryIndex index.html` and that sort of works, except it doesn't work in the case of `someip.com/mysite/reservations/new`. I get the apache `Not Found`